# Hierarchical attributes in XML DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm wondering how to define hierarchical attributes in XML. In fact, I mean how to define attributes in such a way that wherever a specific attributes used, another one(s) could be used. For example, att1 could not be used before att2 and in every case that att1 is used, att2 is allowed.

```
<elem att1="x" att2="y"/>:  is true

<elem att1="x" />:  is true

<elem  att2="y"/>: is not true
```

Comment: u can go to xsd rather than to dtd, to get this functionality

Comment: @Naren, thanks and how to do that using xsd?

Comment: ooops ....there are certain limitations even in the XSD for Attributes.. you cannot set order for attributes.. can u tell me why and where this(specific order) is required for you?